# Send Request to injected Content Script on ContextMenu Click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have injected a code into every page that the user visits. But I want this script to be triggered when the user clicks on the contextMenu thats created by the same extension. In short I have to pass message between the background.html and content script but the trigger should happen on click of context menu.

Here is what I have tried

//background.html

```
function subFunction(info,tab){
        var x = info.selectionText;
            alert("x");//This is working fine
        chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
          chrome.extension.sendRequest({"variable1":x,"type":"y"});
        }); 
    }
chrome.contextMenus.create({"title": "Submit", "onclick": subFunction,"contexts":['selection']});
```

//myscript.js

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        alert("Seems like I am in");
        if(request.type == 'y'){
                   alert("This is" + request.x);
                }
});
```

Can anyone tell me where is this going wrong. From what I understood something is wrong about the tabs.getSelected with the tab.id as the first parameter. But as the source of the click is the context menu, may be its not reading the tab.id or it doesn't understand on which tab I am working on.

Comment: Got this solved.. just replaced the code `chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
          chrome.extension.sendRequest({"variable1":x,"type":"y"});
        });` with `chrome.extension.sendRequest(tab.id,{"variable1":x,"type":"y"});`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all mistaken between `chrome.extension.sendRequest` and `chrome.tabs.sendRequest`. Your method signatures are incorrect for `sendRequest`, it is missing a parameter (which isn't optional). The first parameter is the "extension id" in this case it should be null.

If you want to send a message to the other extension pages, you use `chrome.extension.sendRequest`. If you want to send a message to your content script, you need to use `chrome.tabs.sendRequest`.

In this, case you need to use `chrome.tabs.sendRequest` since your `onRequest` listener is living there. You still need a first parameter which is your tab id.

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {"variable1":x,"type":"y"});
});
```